# Difference between generics in Map function Map<Object,String> and Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, dictionary

Can Somebody tell the difference between `Map<Object, String>` and `Map<String, Object>`.

I am getting same output for both..

[image: <code>Map<String, Object></code>]

[image: <code>Map<Object, String></code>]

Comment: I was never knowing Java has something like that "-Map". Thank you Sri. :)

Comment: Okay sorry for that plz see images now

Comment: Try performing operations on that Map to see the difference between the two types. If you try access values, you'll see that `Map<String, Object>` has values of type Object and the other has values of type String

Comment: Notice that yellow squiggly line under the `oMapper.convertValue` line - that's because of an unchecked cast. This code isn't type-safe.

Comment: thanks@user and   @Andy Turner  - eventhough output is coming can you help me how to avoid that error

Comment: @SriRockz trivially, you can change the type of the map to `Map<?, ?>`. That will deal with the unchecked cast warning. But, of course, you then don't have "correctly"-typed keys and values.

Comment: If you try access values, -- helpful bro.. thanks for the help

Comment: thanks @AndyTurner and any other soluution..

Comment: Please use formatted program text for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using Jackson objectMapper.convert method to covert your object to Map.
So when you are using
     Map
 it is creating 3 items in map with value as object

In this case when you try fetch skills from map, it will return as an Object which you can typecast as list.

But in case of 
    Map
here values are stored as String, that means when you try fetch skills from map, it will return as String object. Now when you try to cast it to list..it will throw exception

Comment: thanks very much, these conversions are bit confusing for me can you plz provide any documention. that would be helpful. TiA sri